# Is it possible to do operations with 2 complex numbers in diferent forms?

Tags: complex-numbers

Say, you have a complex number in standard form and another in trigonometric form, can you do operations with them, for example adding/subtracting, multiplying/diving the two numbers, just like that, or do you have to convert one of them to the other form to be able to do operations?

Comment: What kinds of operations are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Operations can be done in any form but one of them will be more convenient depending on what operation you are referring to. For example, taking powers will be easier in trigo form due to de Moivre's Theorem. Adding/subtracting, however, will be a bit complicated in trigo form.